# Drainage problem on sloping driveway

Tags: drainage, erosion-control

I have a driveway that has a slope. I have a flowerbed right next to the driveway that wraps around the front of the house. The slope causes water to stand after rain or water use and dirt runs onto the driveway in the slope. How can I drain this low area. I put concrete scallops along the driveway and it helps some but having to re-do and need help. Any ideas would help.

Comment: A photo would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a handy man question I'll answer it here. My parents have a large black pipe running from the house to our woods to take water away from the front of the house.

You could use a section of drain tubing after taking apart part of your wall, moving the dirt, and putting the wall back together to remove the water whenever it drains.